# woocommerce cart not working with custom WP theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom wp theme. WooCommerce is installed and up to date. Product pages work, and "add to cart works" however, on the cart page, the shipping calculator simply reloads the page, and changing shipping options that do appear does not update the cart total. tried a default wp theme to test and it works fine there. Any ideas? I used the theme integration guide method of using the woocommerce_content tag and created woocommerce.php. No luck

Comment: Sounds like it may be a JS issue; does the console show any errors?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but no error. What I noticed, there is another site I was working woith that uses a wooTheme. The event listeners listed for the "calculate shipping" element are missing from the site where I am using the custom theme. Could it be that the cart page isn't loading jquery?

Comment: actually I checked, jquery is loading.

Comment: You may have outdated templates. Enable "Template Debug Mode" in WooCommerce>System Status>Tools

Comment: I made the template myself (and i suspect that is part of the problem) but alas, the sys status tools don't have anything to say about it.